# How to change today's date color android CanlendarView

Tags: android-layout, android-styles, calendarview

I have created some custom `styles` for `CalendarView` to change the text colors:

```
    <style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentYellow</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDarker</item>
    </style>
```

And applied them into the calendar like so:

```
<CalendarView
     ...
     android:theme="@style/CalenderViewCustom"
     android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewDateCustomText"
     android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText"
     ...
/>
```

I would like to change the text color of '9', to a different one from the background of '16'.
Currently, both of them are determined by the `colorAccent` attribute.

[image]

Is there any other attribute that would change only one of them separately?

Comment: so you want todays date text color should be differnet and selected date background should be different?

Comment: @Wini Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a pretty cool solution:
We can use the [CompactCalendarView](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView) package which is a little old but still works perfectly fine (Android 26+)

For example to set the "today" color to black:

```
       <com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            ...
            app:compactCalendarCurrentDayTextColor="@android:color/black"
            ...
            />
```